# How to fix G1ANT imap not retrieving any emails?

Tags: gmail, imap, rpa, g1ant

I'm trying to get this G1ANT robot to retrieve unread emails from a test email ID, however the retrieved list `♥list` has a count of zero even when there are two unread emails. How do I get around this? No error messages are displayed as well.

I tried using `imap.getemails` instead of `mail.imap` command also, yet it returns the same results. Here is the code for that line:

`mail.imap imap.getmails host imap.gmail.com port 993 login ♥login password ♥password onlyunreadmessages true sincedate ♥date ignorecertificateerrors true result ♥list`

IMAP is enabled on the email address.

Here is the code:

```
addon net version 4.101.0.0
addon selenium version 4.101.0.0
addon core version 4.101.0.0
addon language version 4.103.0.0

♥login=idgoeshere
♥password=passwordhere

mail.imap imap.gmail.com login ♥login password ♥password sincedate ♥date onlyunreadmessages true ignorecertificateerrors true result ♥list

foreach ♥email in ♥list
    dialog ♥email
end
```

No error messages were shown, simply the automation ends.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `♥date` is a special variable in G1ANT containing the today date. It means that it can't find any emails after today because there was no day after today yet.

Use some direct value instead, for example 16/08/2019 and be sure to use `errorcall` argument as you will probably encounter the exception:

> The folder is not currently open in read-write mode.

You can just ignore it by creating an empty procedure like in the following.

```
mail.imap imap.gmail.com login ♥login password ♥password sincedate ‴16/08/2019‴ onlyunreadmessages true ignorecertificateerrors true errorcall IgnoreError

foreach ♥email in ♥result
    dialog ♥email
end

procedure IgnoreError
end procedure
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use new imap command.

```
imap.open imap.gmail.com login ♥login password ♥password ignorecertificateerrors true
imap.getmails
imap.close
```

Comment: The commands aren't recognized in G1ANT Studio. I am using the latest exe from the website.

Comment: @VIGNESHN don't worry about it. G1ANT is going to release a new version soon (you can see the source code on github) and in the meantime, you can use the mail.imap command in the way that I posted just a second ago.