# how can i connect to imap gmail or outlook.office365.com using G1ant robot RPA

Tags: imap, rpa, g1ant

Can someone help with the below issue:

I'm using the latest version of G1ANT robotic software. I've been able to successfully connect to outlook using the office addon however now I need to access emails on gmail and office 365. As a first step i'm trying to connect to gmail with the below code but I keep getting timeout error. I followed the exact steps in their tutorial but it does not work. Can someone please help:

```
addon net version 4.101.0.0
addon core version 4.101.0.0
addon language version 4.103.0.0

♥yesterday = ⟦date:dd.MM.yyyy⟧02.10.2019
mail.imap imap.gmail.com login myemail@gmail.com password myPasssword sincedate ♥yesterday todate ♥date onlyunreadmessages true ignorecertificateerrors true result ♥list 

foreach ♥element in ♥list
  dialog ♥element
end
```

Comment: Have you checked for firewall?  Most datacenters block IMAP ports by default.

Answer (score 1):

G1ANT doesn't support `mail.imap` command anymore but you can increase the timeout for this command by adding the `timeout` argument and some value (number of milliseconds).

Here's a quote from the manual.

> The timeout argument allows to choose the amount of time (in
>   milliseconds) for the robot to wait for a command to be executed
>   before throwing an error about time expiration.

In your example it will look like below. I increased the timeout, so that it will wait for 100000 milliseconds the longest.

```
mail.imap imap.gmail.com login myemail@gmail.com password myPasssword sincedate ♥yesterday todate ♥date onlyunreadmessages true ignorecertificateerrors true result ♥list timeout 100000
```

Also, please be aware that `mail.imap` command has some issues, for example in order for it to work correctly, it is needed to have for example the `errorcall` argument specified because it almost always throws exception. The problem is explained better on another StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57801125/how-to-fix-g1ant-imap-not-retrieving-any-emails/57974687#57974687).

So I advise you to use this instead:

```
imap.open imap.gmail.com login ♥login password ♥password ignorecertificateerrors true
imap.getmails result ♥list 
imap.close

foreach ♥element in ♥list
  dialog ♥element
end
```